# Gallery Share via Calendar

Tags: applications, calendar

Is there any way I can take a photo/image and create a calendar item based on it.

Ideally I would like to click an image in my gallery then select **share via** and pick my **Calendar app** (Google calendar).

So far the apps I tried do not work with images. For example when I tried 'Share to Calendar V2' it only put the images file name as a description it didn't actually attached it to the event.

So far the only solution I found involves sending an email with attachment to  yourself then creating an event from it, as described here https://www.groovypost.com/tips/add-image-google-calendar-events/  *(this site also does a great job of describing the problem I am trying to solve)*

I want something that is quicker, a one step process.